# Arduino operation enable/disable switches or pins

Tags: arduino, switch-statement

I need some help for my thesis. I got the operations of switch 1, 2, and 3 running perfectly.

As seen in the flow chart, I need to disable switch 2 and 3 so that it won't interrupt switch 1's operation and same with other switches. Then I need to turn on switch 1 first then, disable switch 1 and enable switch 2 right after the operation of switch 1 ends.

After switch 2 is enabled, switch 1 and 3 should remain disabled so that it cannot interrupt switch 2's operation, and then when switch 2 is off, it should be disabled and then enable switch 3.

After enabling switch 3, switch 1 and switch are disabled so that I cannot interrupt switch 3's operation. After switch 3 is turned off, it should go back to the start.

I am coding for the Arduino Mega 2560.

[image]

Here is my code

```
void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
 buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
 buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
if (buttonState1 == HIGH && buttonState2 == LOW && buttonState3 == LOW && counter == 1) {
plantMode();
} else if (buttonState1 == LOW && buttonState2 == HIGH && buttonState3 == LOW && counter == 2) {
maintenance();
} else if (buttonState1 == LOW && buttonState2 == LOW && buttonState3 == HIGH && counter == 3) {
harvestMode();
} else {
if (counter == 1) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   SWITCH  ON   ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(" PLANTING  MODE ");
  digitalWrite(valve, HIGH);
  delay(500);
} else if (counter == 2) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   SWITCH  ON   ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("MAINTENANCE MODE");
  digitalWrite(valve, HIGH);
  delay(500);
} else {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   SWITCH  ON   ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("  HARVEST MODE  ");
  digitalWrite(valve, HIGH);
  delay(500);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What does your code do presently, and where are you stuck exactly? If you want someone to do your debugging for you, and/or to write it for you, I fear you are going to be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

Made a state-machine, with a state for each button-check you do.

*I have not compiled the code, but I'm confident it will work.*

```
int state = 1

void loop() {
  switch(state){
    case 1:
      if (digitalRead(buttonPin1)){
        plantMode();
        state = 2;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (digitalRead(buttonPin2)){
        maintenance();
        state = 3;
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (digitalRead(buttonPin2)){
        maintenance();
      }
      else{
        state = 4;
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (digitalRead(buttonPin3)){
        harvestMode();
        state = 5;
      }
      break;
    case 5:
    if (digitalRead(buttonPin2)){
        harvestMode();
      }
      else{
        state = 1;
      }
      break;
  }   
  else{
    lcdPrint(state);
    delay(500);
  }
}

void lcdPrint(int state){
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("   SWITCH  ON   ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    switch(state){
      case 1:
        lcd.print(" PLANTING  MODE ");
        break;
      case 2:
        lcd.print("MAINTENANCE MODE");
        break;
      case 3:
        lcd.print("  HARVEST MODE  ");
        break;
      default:
        lcd.print("  UNKOWN MODE  ");
    }
    digitalWrite(valve, HIGH);
}
```